# Javascript togglediv and smooth scroll page down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using some code to expand a div to show more content when a button is clicked. I want to now have the page slide down as well when the div is toggled but not sure how to do it with what I currently have.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleDiv(divId) {
       $("#"+divId).toggle();
    }    
    </script>

    <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');" style="background-color: #f9c76a; color:#fff; font-weight:bold; margin-left:2%; padding: 5px 10px; border-bottom:none !important; " class="button2">Button to Expand &gt;</a>

    <div id="myContent" style="display:none; margin-left:2%; padding: 5px 10px; color:#fff; position:relative;">
    Expanded Text Here</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea to work from:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#toggle-button').click(function() {
    $('#toggle-content').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#toggle-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #dcebf9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="toggle-button">Click to toggle</button>

<div id="toggle-content">
  The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly
  on the plain. The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain.
</div>
```

Comment: Was able to use this and applied my smooth scroll code to this, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML** Assign `id` to link

```
<a id="linkTo" style="background-color: #f9c76a; color:#fff; font-weight:bold; margin-left:2%; padding: 5px 10px; border-bottom:none !important; " class="button2" >Button to Expand &gt;</a>

<div id="myContent" style="display:none; margin-left:2%; padding: 5px 10px; color:#fff; position:relative;background-color: #e5eecc;">
Expanded Text Here</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#linkTo").click(function(){
   $("#myContent").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
```

You can have any other element for `div` show/hide.
**JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/6gn2obkn/